# Hire an employee (a consultant)?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, american-english, analogy

I am trying to fill in this sentence:

> “My company is looking to ___ a consultant”.

Is the correct term “hire” or is there a different word that is more fitting when talking about a consultant?

Comment: "Hire" is fine. That's what people do when they ask me to edit a paper. They send me the paper, give me a deadline, and pay me for the work. Even temporary work warrants using "hire". Another word is "engage" (= "hire for job" [thesaurus.com]), but that's not particularly American English. "Employ" is a third, but "hire" is probably the most common.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Hire* is appropriate for a consultant, or more generally for any kind of temporary worker. I’ve also heard “bring in/on a consultant” more than once, which sounds good to me—it conveys more of the “stop in for a few and help out” nature of consulting, I think.

Comment: "bring on"? I'm familiar with "bring in" but not bring **on**...

Comment: @Andrew: *Bring in* also works, and seems to be more common, actually. With *on* might be a thing pecular to the US, or my area of it.

Comment: I agree with Andrew; for me "bring on" is akin to "bring aboard", implying longer-term employment than "bring in".

Answer (score 6):

*Retain* is a good word for this, often used in official contexts.  Historically, it has been used to refer to the hiring of legal services.  That historical context helps emphasise that a specific service has been paid for (rather than a person employed permanently) and that the term of service may be temporary, with a specific goal in mind.

Comment: This isn't quite as good, because in some contexts *retain somebody* means pay him a (comparatively small) fee not to do the work but to be available if he is needed.

Comment: @TimLymington  That's a valid point.  I'd look to make it clear in the surrounding context, or avoid using it if I couldn't.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a consultant, and I tend to be *engaged* as one by my clients.

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, we might be more inclined to *appoint* a consultant.